# Calling Abort on faulted WCF channel causes server side error to be logged

Tags: wcf, logging, error-handling, ierrorhandler

When a FaultException is returned from my WCF service, I need to Abort the channel instead of Closing it. Both my client and service work fine with this approach but after implementing IErrorHandler on the service and logging any exception, I can see that calling Abort on the client causes the service to log:

**System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted...**

I do not want to pollute my service logs with this information and only want to log service related errors. I know I can obviously stop logging any CommunicationExceptions but my service is also a WCF client for other services and CommunicationExceptions raised by these services should be logged.

How can I stop it doing this?

Comment: Could you explain why you would abort rather than close? It may help get you a better answer.

Comment: There is a well known issue with WCF where calling Close() on a channel after an exception has occured throws an exception itself, masking the original exception. Therefore once the channel is faulted, you Abort() rather than Close(). See Tomas's link below and the links that he cites in his blog post itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nobody else has answered the question (Tomas's answer was not relevant), I asked a few experts in the field. Unfortunately, there is no nice way of stopping this and the best that they could come up with was to add logic in IErrorHandler to not log CommunicationExcepions with a message starting with 'The socket connection was aborted'. Not very elegant, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get an exception that covers your underlying exception if you get an exception when calling dispose wich is possible. I wrote a wrapper to deal with scenarios like this, you can read about it on my blog: http://blog.tomasjansson.com/2010/12/disposible-wcf-client-wrapper/

The idea is that you have a wrapper around your channel that deals with the scenario if the dispose method throws an exception.

A small example of how you should use my wrapper:

```
public class ClientWrapperUsage : IYourInternalInterface
{
    public IList<SomeEntity> GetEntitiesForUser(int userId)
    {
        using(var clientWrapper = new ServiceClientWrapper<ServiceType>())
        {
            var response = clientWrapper.Channel.GetEntitiesForUser();
            var entities = response.YourListOfEntities.TranslateToInternal();
            return entities;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have assumed that it existing an extension method for a list that contains the entity that is returned by the service, then you use that method to translate it to internal entities. This is 100 % testable, at least I think :). Just moch the interface `IYourInternalInterface` everywhere you wan't to fake the service.

Comment: That is not the problem. The code works perfectly and generates the correct client exceptions. The problem is the fact that the SERVICE logs an additional error stating that the client has Aborted the channel. In my proxy, I have code similar to yours that calls Abort rather than Close on exceptions and it is this code which is actually causing the extra log on the service. Unless you implement IErrorHandler on the service, you woul not even see this problem but as it is, it is polluting my service error log and making it hard to read any actual errors.

Comment: By the way, there is an issue with the approach in your blog in the fact that any code that uses your ServiceClientWrapper is not unit testable. You might want to take a look at this approach - http://favcode.net/browse/using_castle_dynamic_proxy_to_create_a_wcf_proxy_via_channelfactory - which IMHO works really well. The code is a little bit complicated because it is using Castle Dynamic Proxy, but the advantages of treating a proxy like a normal class make it more than worthwhile. I did try and put this on your blog but was marked as spam!

Comment: Do you get an exception when doint the Abort? Or when do you get the exception? Are you using a wrapper, update your question with the code you have.... that would make it eaiser to answer the question.

Comment: The original (service generated) exception is logged first, then the client aborts the channel and then the second unwanted exception is logged.

Comment: And why isn't this unit testable? Also, testing that piece of code when in use is more an integration test then unit test. They way you should do it is to define an interface that of what you want to get from your service, then let the class that implements that interface use the wrapper. That way you hide the fact that you are using a web service at all which is a good thing. I'll update the answer with a small example.

Comment: Have you debugged the service? Are you getting an exception when you abort to, or what is causing your application to log the second time? Maybe you can force your logger to ignore those kind of exceptions?

Comment: Yes, if you add a wrapper around it all then it can be tested, but this adds more work and more code. With the approach I linked to, you use the service interface and data contracts directly. The equivalent code would be: var securityService = WcfProxy<ISecurityService>.GenerateProxy(); This returns back an ISecurityService implementation which you can inject into the class that needs it. Internally, every time a method is called on the interface, the internal channelfactory creates a new channel, makes the call and closes/aborts the connection as necessary. I think it is genius.

Comment: But if you have that, where do you do the error handling for the `Dispose`? I don't think you will end up with more code actually. And it is pretty nice to be able to use `using(var aaa = ServiceClientWrapper<YourServiceType>()) ´. Also, doing it your way makes your application more coupled to the service interface, and that is nothing I personally like. But it is an interesting alternative :).

Comment: Well, the nice thing with the code I linked to is that handles closing the channel itself, so it does not need to implement idisposable. This is particularly useful when using IoC because if you are injecting a dependency into your component, you should not dispose of it within the component because you do not own it. The trouble is that some IoC container such as Unity will not call dispose on IDisposable objects either so you are left with no code calling Dispose. I agree that this makes you tightly coupled with service interface, but I see this as a good thing. Personal preference I guess!

Comment: I think it is good to be tightly coupled at the right place :). But as you say, that is personal preference. The reason is that who knows what I will use later on to "call" a service or database, if you have that hidden behind an internal interface it is really easy to change and add new ones. But it also depends on your requirement and needs in the application of course, I can definitely see situation where your approach is better.